# How can i split content into columns- separate divs- in yii view

Tags: php, view, yii, pagination

i have a long content for now i have

```
 <p><?php   echo nl2br($model->content);  ?></p>
```

how can i split content longer than some defined length into multiple divs?

like this

```
    <div class="col1>this is some long content</div>
    <div class="col2>  and i mean realllllllly llloong content</div>
```

I think i can/should use pagination for this but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php)

```
<?php
$pages = str_split($model->content, 500);

foreach($pages => $page){
    echo '<div class="page">'.$page.'</div>';
}
?>
```